# How to Properly Configure an LSTM with a Linear Layer for Wake Word Detection

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working on developing a wake word model for my AI assistant. My model architecture includes an LSTM layer to process audio data, followed by a Linear Layer. However, I'm encountering an unexpected output shape from the Linear Layer, which is causing confusion.

After passing the LSTM output (shape: 4, 32, 32) to the Linear Layer, I expected an output shape of (4, 32, 1). However, the actual output shape is (4, 32, 1).

In my binary classification task, I aim to distinguish between two classes: 0 for "do not wake up" and 1 for "wake up the AI." My batch size is 32, and I anticipated the output to be in the shape (32, 1) to represent one prediction for each audio MFCC input.

Could someone advise on the correct configuration of the Linear Layer or any processing steps needed to achieve the desired output shape of (32, 1)? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. You need to reshape your data to (32, 1) or (1, 32) in order for your linear layer to work. You can achieve this by adding a dimension with `torch.unsqueeze()` or even directly with `torch.view()`. If you use the unsqueeze function, the new shape should be (32, 1). If you use the view function, the new shape should be (1, 32).

Comment: But if i reshape it, wouldn't that be a loss of some data. Becuase (4,32,1) has 4 times 32X1. or am i really not seeing something or thinking wrong? forgive my noobish questions

Comment: It works if you want to do a binary classification. If you have more than 2 classes, you will need to transform your labels to one-hot encoding.

Comment: i also heard that i shouldnt feed the linear with hidden output, i should make like hn[-1]. Is that also correct ?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.